# How do I make Apache stop logging " ModSecurity: Access denied"?

Tags: apache, logging

I have Apache set up on a Linux server and have mod_security enabled. I have a few lines that look like:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "^/*admin" drop,phase:1
```

Because there is no `/admin` on my website, and I don't want to waste the server resources to serve a 404 page to a bot or hacker.

I've noticed that whenever a page such as `/admin` is visited, I see in my Apache access logs that an HTTP 301 status with 0 bytes of content was returned (which is exactly what I want). However, I also get a `ModSecurity: Access denied with connection close (phase 1). Pattern match "^/*admin" at REQUEST_URI.` line in my Apache error logs.

Is there any way I can continue having mod_security append these connection drops to my access logs, but not append anything to my error logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you don't have [log](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#log) specified - from the documentation on ModSecurity:

> **Description**: Indicates that a successful match of the rule needs to be logged.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> SecAction phase:1,id:117,pass,initcol:ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR},log
> ```
>
> This action will log matches to the Apache *error log* file and the
>   ModSecurity audit log.

Instead specify [nolog](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#nolog):

> **Description**: Prevents rule matches from appearing in both the *error* and audit logs.
>
> **Example**:
>
> ```
> SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent "Test" allow,nolog,id:121
> ```
>
> Although nolog implies noauditlog, you can override the former by
>   using nolog,auditlog.

Comment: I can't get `nolog` to work. I've tried `SecRule REQUEST_URI "^/*admin" drop,phase:1,nolog` and `SecRule REQUEST_URI "^/*admin" nolog,drop,phase:1`, and yes I restarted Apache both times. The documentation doesn't say anything about using `nolog` and `phase:#` at the same time though. Could this be causing the problem?

Comment: There's an example in the docs using `phase` and `nolog` together [here](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#wiki-SecAction) using `SecAction`, and another example [here](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#phase) for `phase`.

Comment: I tried using it that way and it still didn't work. Maybe it's because of `drop`?

Comment: Try it without - I see examples [here](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#drop) for `drop` with `phase`, but using `log` (though I'm not sure why it would impact `nolog`).

Comment: That's really strange. Suddenly, `nolog` works. I'm not sure what was wrong, but all I know is that it's working now. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad it works :-)

Comment: BTW, I had setup and tested the configuration on my end and it worked right off, but I made sure to kill off all Apache processes first, so that might have helped versus restarting it.

Comment: I figured out what it was. I have ports 80 and 443 (HTTP and HTTPS) open, and in a `.htaccess` file I have it set to redirect all port 80 requests to port 443. In my virtual hosts file, I was re-writing all of my security rules (one set for port 80, and another set of the same rules for port 443). Even with `nolog` specified on port 80, it was still appending to `error_log`. After removing all of the security rules from port 80 (because I realized they weren't necessary), everything gets forwarded to port 443 now and then is successfully dropped without being logged. No clue why that happens.

Comment: I see, thanks for the update. Lots of variables...nothing technical is ever too easy ;-)